# JavaFX - How to add attachments/File links to each tableview object

Tags: listview, javafx, hyperlink, tableview, javafx-8

I've been researching into attaching files (such as pdfs, word, emails, etc.) or File Path links to each TableView object/row. I guess the closest implementation would be `ListView<HyperLinks>` but I was not able to find if there was such for `ListView<Files>` or code that could open file or go to the File Explorer Path where as hyperlinks are for the internet URLS.

I'm hoping for each row/student, when you click on it, a popup appears and it is a ListView displaying the following, e.g.

```
immunizationRecords.pdf (or C:/Path/to/immunizationRecords);
transcript.pdf (or C:/Path/to/transcript)
.
.
add link to list.......delete link from list
```

Say you click on transcript.pdf, or the path, it would either open the pdf, or is a link to open the path in the File Explorer for you to open yourself.

I haven't found anything upon this subject or in documentation either, only the `Hyperlinks` but that's different still. Is there such an implementation or would I have to maybe have the user manually input the `String filePath`, to which they would put in the `FileChooser` that would then go to the path?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Update, I just found out about

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File());
```

I was able to open a file on clicking the TableView row.
So my solution for now is that I can do is on click of the "link" in the ListView popup, I will just pass the String value to the Desktop.open() to open the file.

I'll probably edit this post to include the relevant code.